# iPhone Sdk: Is it possible to add an UIImageView as a file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

i was just wondering wether it is possible to add an uiimageview as a .m and .h class file because you can just choose a subclass from uiview or uitableviewcell in apple's templates and it than automatically creates the .m and .h files.
Is there a way to do the same for an UIImageView or is it possible to somehow "turn" the UIView into an imageview?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create you own *subclass* of `UIImageView`, yes. And if you're very brave, you could also create your own subclass of `UIView` as well, that would take a `UIImage` and paint that in it's `-(void)drawRect:` method. Then it would be much like a `UIImageView`.

But, why would you?

**edit** subclassing `UIImageView` is easiest by starting with the `UIView` subclass template, and then just replacing the word `UIView` with `UIImageView`, so you get:

```
@interface UIImageViewPlus : UIImageView {
    // ...
}
```

That's all there is to it, now just use `UIImageViewPlus` wherever you would use `UIImageView`.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking the syntax for how to do that. But, I agree, *why* is a better first question...

Comment: Sure? The syntax is given by XCode as the OP states. And the main question seems "how to turn a UIView into a UIImageView" (and an implied "without using UIImageView")

Comment: Yea i was asking for the syntax of a subclass of uiimageview and i want to this because in this subclass i want to define a whole bunch of labels and other stuff so these things can be accessed from other classes

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView is a UIView since it inherits directly from UIView so I'm not sure what you are asking about.....you can easily create a subclass of the UIImageView to do whatever customization you require....

Comment: Yes but how do i create that subclass?

Comment: @interface MyCustomUIViewClass : UIView